# to check input time exists between two time range or not

Tags: php, mysql

I want to how to check whether given time lies in two time range or not.
For example: 22:00 < 22:30 , here condition getting false. Thanks in advance.

```
$time1="11:00"; 
$time2="22:30"; 
$currenttime=date("22:00"); 

if($time1 - $currenttime < 0 && $currenttime - $time2 < 0 ) { 
    echo "Lies in range"; 
} else { 
    echo "Not lies in range"; 
}
```

Comment: show your code to get proper solution ....

Comment: $time1="11:00";
$time2="22:30";
$currenttime=date("22:00");  // currenttime

if($time1 - $currenttime < 0  && $currenttime - $time2 < 0 )    
{ 
echo "Lies in range"; 
}
else
{
 echo "Not lies in range"; 
}

Comment: diff1 = $time1 - $currenttime;
diff2 = $currenttime - $time2;

if(diff1  < 0 && diff2 < 0) { echo "Lies in range"; } 
else { echo "Not lies in range"; }

Try This....

Comment: and i think you should check your condition it might be wrong there is no output come from it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code should work:

```
$time1 = strtotime("11:00");
$time2 = strtotime("22:30");
$currenttime = strtotime("22:00");
if ($time1 - $currenttime < 0 && $currenttime - $time2 < 0)
{
    echo "Lies in range";
}
else
{
    echo "Not lies in range";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution . It works great. You saved me .

Comment: This way you can't check if a time is within an interval that includes midnight: `$time1 = strtotime("22:00");` and `$time2 = strtotime("06:00");`.

Comment: $time1 = strtotime("13 feb 2016 22:00");
$time2 = strtotime("14 feb 2016 06:30");
$currenttime = strtotime("14 feb 2016 05:59");

Adding Date would solve that.

Thank you for heads up!